# difference between Hibernate Session and EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

What is the difference between the Hibernate `Session` class and the `EntityManager` class? I know that `EntityManager` implements the Java Persistence API, but I am not sure what its relation is with `Session`. Are they related at all?

Answer (score 41):

`Session` is a hibernate-specific API, `EntityManager` is a standardized API for JPA. You can think of the `EntityManager` as an adapter class that wraps `Session` (you can even get the `Session` object from an `EntityManager` object via the `getDelegate()` function).

This is not dissimilar to other Java APIs around (for example, JDBC is a standard API, each vendor adapts its product to the API via a driver that implements the standard functions).

Comment: is there a difference between them in functionality or they more or less identical?

Comment: They are not identical (functions have different names and even different purposes, annotations are different, etc.). What hibernate (and every other JPA vendor around) does is provide an adapter object that creates the EntityManager functionality by calling the native hibernate API.

Comment: does entity manager creates a new session everytime requested? just curious about it